# Can you port a DirectX game to Google Native Client?

Tags: directx, google-nativeclient

It's my first time trying Native Client. I read an article and found each sample about 3D graphics used OpenGL ES 2.0. Can I port a Direct3D game to Native Client, or do I have to rewrite my code with OpenGL ES?

Answer (score 4):

You would have to rewrite your D3D code to OpenGL ES 2.0 (or introduce a runtime translation layer that translated DirectX calls to OpenGL ES).

Native Client is designed to be portable across operating systems (currently Windows, Linux, Mac OS, and Chrome OS), so you cannot use anything that is specific to one operating system. In Native Client you can think of the Pepper API (PPAPI) as your system call interface for accessing capabilities like graphics, audio, networking, etc. And for hardware accelerated graphics specifically, Native Client supports OpenGL ES 2.0.